# Ability to export functional component in React JS / Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I am using redux forms in react js.Due to reusabily purpose I placed a functional component in a seperate file as below.

**RenderFields.js**

```
import React from "react";

function renderFields({
  input,
  label,
  type,
  meta: { touched, error, warning }
}) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="control">
        <label className="field">{label}</label>
        ..........................
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default renderFields;
```

And I just want to use that in terminal class component.

**Terminal.js**

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";

    import renderFields from "../../renderComponents/RenderFields";

    class Terminal extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          name: "",
          uid: "",
          status: null
        };
      }

    ......................

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="Terminal">
            <div className="card">

              <div id="Terminalform">
                <form
                  class="container-fluid terminalform "
                  onChange={this.handleSubmit}
                >
                  <div class="content">
                    {/*Terminal Name */}
                    <FormGroup controlId="name" bsSize="large">
                      <ControlLabel>TERMINAL NAME</ControlLabel>
                      <Field
                        style={{ width: "100%" }}
                        component={renderFields}
                        name="name"
                        type="text"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                      />
                    </FormGroup>





                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    Terminal = reduxForm({
      form: "terminalform"
    })(Terminal);
```

When I was runnning these files I am getting an error as below.

Can someone help me out for solving this error?

[image]

**Update**

I wrapped RenderField function into a component as below

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class RenderFields extends Component {
  render() {
    const { label, input, type, touched, error, warning } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="control">
          <label className="field">{label}</label>
          <input
            className="input"
            style={{ width: "100%" }}
            {...input}
            placeholder={label}
            type={type}
          />

          <br />
          <div style={{ color: "red" }}>
            {touched &&
              ((error && <span>{error}</span>) ||
                (warning && <span>{warning}</span>))}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default RenderFields;
```

But I still come up with the same error.

Comment: How you are using Terminal component?

Comment: Component names need to be capitalised - RenderFields

Comment: React will treat 'renderFields' as default HTML tag and not React element. You should rename 'renderFields' to 'RenderFields'

Comment: I found [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-txan3s?file=reducer.js) with similar structure. You could use for reference

Comment: @tarzenchugh yes. That's how I did earlier and it was perfectly working. I just wanted to keep it in a seperate component in order to increase the reusability.

Comment: @Ruks - Now you could just create new component `RenderFields` (make sure first letter is uppercase as mentioned in comments above) and import it wherever required, it should work perfectly fine.

Comment: @tarzenchugh I did as you said and updated the question as well. I still get the same error.